# Airflow got error while processing large number of tasks

Tags: mysql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running a dag with large number of tasks(greater than 5000), it fails with below error after examining dag run.

[2020-12-15 00:43:53,765] {scheduler_job.py:166} ERROR - Got an exception! Propagating...

The strange thing is the dag runs successfully if the number of tasks are like 1000 or 2000 or lesser.

Any idea what is going on here? Not sure why same task entries are being reinserted into mysql table again.

Airflow is set up with local executor, mysql database as metastore.

Below is dag code

```
main_dag_id = 'myDag'

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'provide_context': True
}

dag = DAG(
    main_dag_id,
    schedule_interval='0 3,9 * * *',
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args=args
    )

def start(*args, **kwargs):
    //something

def end(*args, **kwargs):
    //something

def doSomeWork(name, index, *args, **kwargs):
    //something

starting_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='start',
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=start,
    op_args=[])
    
ending_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='end',
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=end,
    op_args=[])

for index in range(5000):
    dynamicTask1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='raw_view_' + str(index),
        dag=dag,
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=doSomeWork,
        op_args=['raw_view', index])

    starting_task.set_downstream(dynamicTask1)
    dynamicTask1.set_downstream(ending_task)

starting_task.set_downstream(ending_task)
```

Complete log

```
2020-12-14 23:00:11,272] {scheduler_job.py:1284} INFO - Processing myDag
[2020-12-14 23:00:11,286] {scheduler_job.py:759} INFO - Examining DAG run <DagRun myDag @ 2020-12-14 23:00:09.937961+00:00: manual__2020-12-14T23:00:09.937961+00:00, externally triggered: True>
[2020-12-14 23:00:12,686] {scheduler_job.py:166} ERROR - Got an exception! Propagating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1264, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 148, in do_executemany
    rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 279, in executemany
    r = self._query(qs)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 371, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 335, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'start-myDag-2020-12-14 23:00:09.937961' for key 'PRIMARY'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 158, in _run_file_processor
    pickle_dags)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1611, in process_file
    self._process_dags(dagbag, dags, ti_keys_to_schedule)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1295, in _process_dags
    self._process_task_instances(dag, tis_out)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 780, in _process_task_instances
    run.verify_integrity(session=session)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagrun.py", line 400, in verify_integrity
    session.commit()
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1042, in commit
  File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit
      self._prepare_impl()
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
      self.session.flush()
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2523, in flush
      self._flush(objects)
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2664, in _flush
      transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
      exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
      raise exception
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2624, in _flush
      flush_context.execute()
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
      rec.execute(self)
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
      uow,
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
      insert,
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1083, in _emit_insert_statements
      c = cached_connections[connection].execute(statement, multiparams)
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1020, in execute
      return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
      return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_clauseelement
      distilled_params,
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1324, in _execute_context
      e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1518, in _handle_dbapi_exception
      sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
    File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1518, in _handle_dbapi_exception
       sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
     File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
       raise exception
     File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1264, in _execute_context
       cursor, statement, parameters, context
     File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 148, in do_executemany
       rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
     File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 279, in executemany
       r = self._query(qs)
     File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 371, in _query
       rowcount = self._do_query(q)
     File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 335, in _do_query
       db.query(q)
     File "/blahblah/AIRFLOW-1.10.10-python3.6.8_e3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
       _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
   sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'start-myDag-2020-12-14 23:00:09.937961' for key 'PRIMARY'")
   [SQL: INSERT INTO task_instance (task_id, dag_id, execution_date, start_date, end_date, duration, state, try_number, max_tries, hostname, unixname, job_id, pool, pool_slots, queue, priority_weight, operator, queued_dttm, pid, executor_config) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)]
   [parameters: (('start', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 5002, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'), ('end', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 1, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'), ('raw_view_0', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 2, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'), ('raw_view_1', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 2, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'), ('raw_view_2', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 2, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'), ('raw_view_3', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 2, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'), ('raw_view_4', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 2, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'), ('raw_view_5', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 2, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.')  ... displaying 10 of 5002 total bound parameter sets ...  ('raw_view_4998', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 2, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'), ('raw_view_4999', 'myDag', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 23, 0, 9, 937961), None, None, None, None, 0, 0, '', 'duser', None, 'default_pool', 1, 'default', 2, 'PythonOperator', None, None, b'\x80\x04\x95\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94.'))]
   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
   [2020-12-14 23:00:16,205] {scheduler_job.py:154} INFO - Started process (PID=2024199) to work on /dags/myDag.py
   [2020-12-14 23:00:16,207] {scheduler_job.py:1562} INFO - Processing file /dags/myDag.py for tasks to queue
   [2020-12-14 23:00:16,208] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-12-14 23:00:16,208] {dagbag.py:396} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dags/myDag.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase if anyone else run into same issue, the fix was to bump up dag_file_processor_timeout, 300 secs worked vs default 50 secs.